# Get a function from another class in the same namespace (on a clone object) in unity, c#

Tags: c#, function, class, unity-game-engine, namespaces

I can't quite figure out what the right solution is so I hope someone can help me/explain what I am doing wrong:

I have two classes in the same namespace `farm`; `WhichAnimal.cs` and `Pig.cs`. I try to get the `EatFood()` function from `Pig.cs` to `WhichAnimal.cs`. The object with the `Pig.cs` script attached to it, is only spawned when the scene starts and is a clone of the prefab in assets/prefabs folder.

What am I doing wrong/how do I get the `EatFood()` function to work in the `WhichAnimal` script?

Pig Class:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace Farm {
class Pig : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject Balloon;
    public Text text;
    public string name;

    public void EatFood()
    {
        Balloon.SetActive(true);
        text.text = "";
    }
}
```

WhichAnimal Class:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Farm {
public class WhichAnimal : MonoBehaviour {

    public Pig pig;

     public void Start() {
         pig = GetComponent<Pig>().EatFood();
     }

     public void GiveFood() {
        pig.EatFood();
     }
}
```

Comment: In your Start method of the WhichAnimal class, u set the pig equals the method EatFood(). Try an remove this and see if it works (to this instead pig = GetComponent<Pig>()).

Comment: I attached the prefab in my assets/prefabs folder to the public pig in the inspector, but it's set to empty when the scene starts.. pig = GetComponent<Pig>(); doesnt seem to give any errors though. Is there a way I can call the script from the clone?

Comment: Is the Pig component attached to the same gameobject as the WhichAnimal Component? Can you possibly add a screenshot of your editor with the empty script displayed, so I can see your gameobject

Comment: Also my first comment is wrong. What you did is possible in Unity, calling a method upon assignment with .GetComponent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is from :

```
public void Start() {
     pig = GetComponent<Pig>().EatFood();
}
```

`GetComponent<Pig>()` will try to find a component (class derived from monobehaviour) `Pig` that is attached to the same `gameObject` as the script that is calling `GetComponent`. That means for this to work you need `Pig` and `WhichAnimal` on the same `gameObject`.

So first solution, get an instance of `Pig` when you instantiate the `gameObject` with this script.

Other solution, use `Object.FindObjectOfType<Pig>()` to find an instance of `Pig` or `FindObjectsOfType<Pig>()` to have an array of `Pig` if there is more than one ^^.

But use it with care, not each frame, just once. It can be resource consuming.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
 pig = GetComponent<Pig>().EatFood();
```

is wrong. GetComponent() would replaces the reference to the pig (which you set up in inspector) with a null (unless you have a  component on the same gameObject), but EatFood returns void, not a pig, so that line shouldn't even compile

If Pig pig is a reference that exists already, you can skip this line, and just call EatFood() on the pig.

What you should watch for is that if pig is a prefab, it needs to have the baloon reference, otherwise the Baloon.SetActive() might return a null. I think you might want to call it on an object that exists already (gets serialised by an inspector), rather than on a prefab

Comment: pig = GetComponent<Pig>().EatFood(); Is actually doable in Unity without compile or runtime errors.

Comment: I do not believe so, I just tried pasting the code above, and even after making Pig public you still get a compile time error: Assets/WhichAnimal.cs(12,36): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `void' to `Farm.Pig'

Comment: I see. I thought that this was possible since it is with AddComponent. My bad